# Nginx proxy_pass to another port with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, proxypass

My problem is following: I use Wordpress on Nginx with "pretty links". I also run 2 other services on ports 88 and 1234 and I want to make a subdomains bugs.mydomain and mail.mydomain. I did the proxypass on location / but it's working only for the main directory, anything that is after the domain/ is falling into Wordpress "pretty links" mechanism. Do you have any idea how to solve this? My config files below:
The server config:

```
server {
    listen   <IP>:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/domain;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name domain www.domain;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            if ( $host ~ "bugs.domain" ) {
                proxy_pass http://domain:88;
            }

            if ( $host ~ "mail.domain" ) {
                proxy_pass http://domain:1234;
            }
    }

    location /doc/ {
            alias /usr/share/doc/;
            autoindex on;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    include /home/domain/public_html/nginx.conf;
    }
```

the config for specified domain (with Wordpress):

```
#First there is many rewrites for the W3TC plugin, like minification, caches etc
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
{
    set $host_without_www $1;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
}
#
# unless the request is for a valid file, send to bootstrap
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

Now, when I enter domain:88 or domain:1234 it works. When I enter bugs.domain the website loads, but no CSS or images works as the url is bugs.domain/somapath and this falls into the Wordpress bootstrap. I run out of the ideas.

Answer (score 3):

why create only 1 server with if's in it, separate the servers

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bugs.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:88;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mail.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:1234;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   # the rest of your main server
   #
}
```

Comment: That's probably good solution, thanks! However I just found what was the real problem, I will post it in few minutes

Comment: I don't think you meant to have colons in your directives? "server_name bugs.example.com" not "server_name: bugs.example.com"

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was completely different then I thought. it was failing on this line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

The problem was, that file index.html didn't exist, I only had index.php. Changing it solved the problem.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to put the `try_files` before the `if`, It's more logical to put the if's first